# How to put HTML code in a jQuery array as variable, then use that var to replace content?

Tags: jquery, html, arrays, variables, element

There is a page with a list of links, which need to change the information on the right. I tried something in jQuery, but I'm doing something wrong, of course.

**HTML**

```
<div class="left">
    <a name="top"></a>
    <div class="title">
        <a class="options" href="#top" data-value="0">
            Title
        </a>
    </div>
    <ul>
        <a class="options" href="#top" data-value="1"><li>Link 1</li></a>
        <a class="options" href="#top" data-value="2"><li>Link 2</li></a>
        <a class="options" href="#top" data-value="3"><li>Link 3</li></a>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="right">
    <p>Default text</p>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

***Please note that I must keep the quotation marks in the content, is there another way of containing the vars? My original vars have both single and double quotes.***

```
var content = [

            "<p>Content 1</p>",
            "<p>"Content 2"</p>",
            "<p>Content 3</p>"
            ];

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.options').click(function() {
        $('.right').html(content[$(this).data("value")]);
    });
});
```

How can I put HTML code, including quotes, into variables?

Comment: Are there any errors printed on the console?

Comment: you're missing the commas in the content array

Comment: Fix array syntax, then beware array is zero index base

Comment: Ah, I forgot to add commas in this example. However, I do have commas, this isn't the issue. The only error is this: SyntaxError: missing ] after element list, because my code has quotation marks in the text... how can I put full-fledged HTML with quotes and tags into variables? Thanks everyone who responded so quick as well.

Comment: @user2959040 now also have a syntax error. there are multiple double quotations present in the array.

Comment: It's better you post some of the actual code unless you simulate it correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your content var needs commas between the array items:

```
var content = [
            "<p>\"Content 1\"</p>",
            "<p>\"Content 2\"</p>",
            "<p>\"Content 3\"</p>"
            ];
```

And also your data-values need to start at 0 (not 1).  Or you could account for it in your javascript e.g.

```
$('.right').html(content[$(this).data("value")-1]);
```

Comment: Yes, my original full code (over 15 variables) has the commas, I stupidly forgot to add them in the example. It is corrected now, along with an example of the quotes I need to use.

Comment: If you want quotes in the content of the array delimit them with backslashes.  I've edited my answer to show.

Answer (score 1):

```
var content = [
            "<p>Content 1</p>",
            "<p>Content 2</p>",
            "<p>Content 3</p>"
            ];
```